# Hide and show contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, html5-canvas

I'm implementing a web based application in which the help section has "show more faqs" link that will expand the page with more content from the category. The section should pull all faqs question and answers from category which are retrieved from database. Im stuck in finding out as to how to write a html based code to show the remaining contents.

Show more faqs

Comment: what does your controller code look like?  and your view code?  why should it be html based?

Comment: You better give us a perspective of your controller and stuff. Anyways, assuming defaults, I have posted my answer. Hope, it helps.

Comment: View :  <a href="#" id = "1" style="margin-left: 10px;" OnClick="$('#on').toggle(); $('#1').hide(); return false;">Show more faqs</a>
        <div id = "on" style = "display:none;" >

Comment: That's the view part buddy, not the controller.

Comment: Am new to rails so not sure of certain concepts, sorry for that. Would yu explain a little more on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to do it:

1. **If you are not comfortable with Ajax:** Load all the remaining FAQs during the page load and wrap them in a DIV with hidden class. When the show-more link is clicked, remove the hidden-class from the div.
2. **If you are OK with Ajax:** On click of the show-more link, send an Ajax request. It should send across the remaining FAQs. On success of the Ajax-request, append it to the existing FAQs HTML. https://gist.github.com/satyatechsavy/7673942

Comment: Mark the answer as best if this really helps you. Will help others identify the answer easily.

Comment: This is my view part <a href="#" id = "1" style="margin-left: 10px;" OnClick="$('#on').toggle(); $('#1').hide(); return false;">Show more faqs</a>
        <div id = "on" style = "display:none;" >

Comment: Am new to rails so not sure of certain concepts, sorry for that. Would yu explain a little more on it